# Client side Socket.io override or hendle disconnect event

Tags: socket.io

Hi everyone I'musing Socket.io
But I have a problem. There are two type of clients, client "A" with custom events and client "B" with some other custom events, but here is the problem:

The disconnect event is equal for all clients and according to socket.io is not possible to override and call "A_disconnect" or "B_disconnect" but only "disconnect" event, so how can I notice if client A or client B is disconnected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to store your clients type into a map/array at server level?(e.g. a global collection that lives for all server time)

You save the type of client and a reference during the connection into the map/array so when you intercept disconnect you could call an appropriate method base on the type of the client you have previously stored.

Another approach is t connect clients A on a socket.io instance and clients B on another instance, but this not scale well and in my opinion is not a good choice in your case.

Hope this helps of give you some hints.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, I stored the clients socket in two different array but they could have same id. I resolved checking both if the socket in array of clients A[id of client disconnected] is connected or not, if not delete.